# Time Scales Of Processes In Molecular Dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability, molecular-dynamics

Suppose I run a molecular dynamics simulation of a fluid sandwiched between solid walls which are periodic in the lateral directions and finite in the direction of the fluid film thickness. Now, I exert a constant force normal to the upper wall, hence applying a pressure in the fluid. In order for the fluid to equilibriate, I run the simulation for a "sufficiently long" time until say the fluctuations in the fluid thickness have become negligible. At 
this point, I start moving the lower wall at a constant velocity in one
of the lateral directions and average the fluid density over a long time.

I expect that the density of the fluid is uniform, in the thickness direction.
This is however, not the case. This makes me suspect that I wrongly estimated
the equilibriation time and in general, raise the question of how one would 
think about the time scale of processes in an MD simulation.

In the case of this fluid problem, a lower bound for the time required
is provided by $L/c$, where $L$ is the largest lateral dimension and $c$ is the speed of sound. But, this works out to be a small number which my simulation time has exceeded by ${\cal O}(10^2)$. Therefore, is there any 
other way of finding a bound on the time scale of this equilibriation process?

In particular, using Markov State Models, have some time scales for such 
processes in polymeric fluids been arrived at?

I understand that non-uniform density may not necessarily be a time-scale
related problem and if you have other suggestions on why this could be happening, I would be very grateful!

Here is a plot of the density along $z= c$ planes for two values of $c$ seperated by 2 Angstroms. As you can see, the density is not uniform along $z$,
the thickness direction. 
[image: plot of density]

Here is the picture of the geometry.
[image: Geometry of the problem]

Comment: i am not an expert, but perhaps the mean free path and average particle speed are a more appropriate length and velocity scale?

Comment: Given that I have a dense fluid, using the molecular diameter and the thermal speed would result in a very small time scale $\approx 1$ ps. However, to get any reasonably noise-free data from an MD simulation, we would have to run the simulation for much longer. So, although this seems like a good time scale for molecular diffusion, it doesn't help in deciding how long to run an MD simulation.

Comment: You are effectively simulating a couette flow, correct? Do you get a linear velocity profile? If not that would indicate you haven't run the simulation for long enough. Unfortunately we usually characterize the timescale for couette flow as a diffusive one $L^2/\nu$, can you estimate the viscosity $\nu$ in your system?

Comment: How thick is the layer, and what exactly is the fluid you're modelling?

Comment: Also, with what speed are you moving the lower wall?

Comment: @nluigi : I could use the scale $D^2/\nu$, where $D$ is the length scale in the thickness direction, since I am simulating a couette flow.  This time scale is also low ($\approx 10 $ picoseconds) compared to my simulation time.

Comment: @lemon      I am modelling n-hexadecane (which, from my other simulations, appears to be Newtonian in the regime I am simulating) and moving the wall at 20 m/s. The temperature in the system is controlled by thermostatting some layers of the solid wall and there is no thermostatting in the liquid. there is no appreciable temperature increase in the system.

Comment: You're at a shear rate where you might reasonably expect some shear thinning effects. Can you post a plot of the density profile?

Comment: @lemon I have added the plots of the density and a VMD picture of the simulation box. I hope this makes the problem clear!

Comment: The purple-green-pink layers is the wall you are applying the pressure to, correct? It seems to me there might be an issue with your periodic boundary conditions. There seems to be some build up of particles at those boundaries. Have you checked them?

Comment: The boundary conditions are fine. But the curved upper wall certainly offers some hints. Firstly, how exactly are you applying the force to the upper wall?

Comment: I am applying pressure by adding a constant force on all the atoms in the pink layer (the top most layers in the picture). Total pressure = (number of pink atoms)*(force on each atom in the - z direction)/(area of the surface)

Comment: Okay, that's fine. I suspect the problem is how you're 'getting up to speed'. Rather than set the lower wall's velocity straight to 20 m/s, you could  gradually increase it; or you could give the fluid the correct (linear) velocity profile to begin with. Alternatively/additionally, you should constrain the upper wall to prevent it from bending (I hope you're using lammps - it's easy to do with `fix rigid`).

Comment: @lemon Thanks! The wall is fixed with `fix rigid`. I was able to get a constant density profile and a linear velocity profile starting from a random initial distribution, for a plane couette flow. I don't recognize the issue here, however.

Comment: It's hard to say but presumably any sufficiently large inhomogeneity in the fluid's density will correspond to a local drop in pressure; the local drop in pressure will draw the upper plate downwards in that region. Once the plate locally depresses, it causes the fluid velocity to increase in that one region which (through something akin to Bernoulli's principle) causes a greater pressure drop and therefore draws the plate down further in that region, and so on. That's my guess anyway. If you animate the trajectory it may become clear.